# Sync Android SDKs failed [Android Studio 2.1.1]

Tags: android, android-studio, import, synchronization, project

```
The path
'C:\Users\studio1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'
does not belong to a directory.

Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead:
'D:\Android\sdk'
and will modify the project's local.properties file.
```

I get this error when trying to open an existing Android Studio Project.
Android SDK is installed in `D:\Android\sdk` . How to fix that?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4adz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself. Had to change local.propeties to path D:\Android\sdk